Unable to login, push and pull on/to artifactory docker repository in AKS
Good day everyone.
I am currently trying to create an Artifactory instance in kubernetes using the Jfrog provided helm charts.
The problem is that when i am trying to login, push or pull i get the following error:
unable to decode token response: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
I executed a curl command against the registry url but i get the following:
curl -v jfrog.customurl.com:443
* Trying 10.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to jfrog.customurl.com (10.0.0.1) port 443

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: jfrog.customurl.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*

\< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
\< Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2024 07:10:19 GMT
\< Content-Type: text/html
\< Content-Length: 248
\< Connection: close
\<
\<html\>
\<head\>\<title\>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port\</title\>\</head\>
\<body\>
\<center\>\<h1\>400 Bad Request\</h1\>\</center\>
\<center\>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port\</center\>
\<hr\>\<center\>nginx\</center\>
\</body\>
\</html\>

* Closing connection

I read that this was because apparently there is a reverse proxy in front of the Artifactory which is an nginx-ingress for which i am using the following configuration as described by Jfrog:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        rewrite ^/(v2)/token /artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token;
        rewrite ^/(v2)/([^\/]*)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$2/$1/$3;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url https://jfrog.customurl.com

And the http settings are as follows using the repository path docker access method:
Artifactory - Docker HTTp settings
Using the subdomain option is unfortunately not possible because of problems that would give with company rules as is using http(which works but is also not allowed).
I have tried to follow the instructions from jfrog here:
Artifactory Helm configuration
Jfrog Ingress
I also tried to add the nginx snippet provided by artifactory.
Basically i would expect to push and pull docker images as usual.
I have been banging my head against the wall for quite a while with this issue and would love some help or pointer as to how i can solve this.

For others who might experience this issue: The documentation on the jfrog website seems to be faulty. I resolved this issue by removing the following lines from the example above:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
rewrite ^/(v2)/token /artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token;
rewrite ^/(v2)/([^\/]*)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$2/$1/$3;

